How was Vegito able to retain his consciousness in his candy form?
How was Vegito able to retain his consciousness and then fight after he was turned into a candy by Super Majin Buu?

This is likely a plot hole (or more likely than that, simply a gag to show of strength, not dissimilar to the Arale appearances). But one can rationalize this by not looking at how Vegito was able to do something extraordinary but more so how other victims were not able to do something ordinary.
The first usage of the transfiguration beam was the first on screen appearance of Majin Buu (the fat one) against Dabura, where he turned Dabura into a cookie. What we do know is that Dabura was not literally turned into a cookie, a cookie being an inanimate, lifeless object. This we can infer because when he was turned into a cookie, he didn't lose his life (as the characters explain, those turned to stone will only be restored when Dabura dies). He did die when he was eaten, not unlike how almost any live animal dies when they are eaten. From this, we can infer that the transfiguration beam only turns their appearance into another shape, preferably one that is feeble and non-threatening (similar to how a Ginyu turned into a frog, but retained his abilities).
This leaves the explanation of why Dabura (and the other victims, like the humans) appeared to be unable to fight after the transformation. The simplest explanation is that given the circumstances (Dabura especially) they were in a state of shock or disbelief. The human victims are of course weak and likely couldn't fly. As we can infer from Daima, sudden changes in the bodies of characters generally render them immobile due to lack of familiarity with the form. Vegito however, through Goku, already was aware of the transfiguration technique and was prepared when his body changed. Vegito can, of course, also fly so he could still fight in his form just by flying at high speeds (and ramming into his opponent).

Which reminds me. Are there always gonna be plot holes in anime, cartoons, movies, video games, & stories?

@Henkyo Plot holes usually occur for 2 reasons: 1. different writers and the second writer didn't really study the work of the first one. and 2. Too much time passed and the writer simply forgets as part of getting old (what occurred for much of the plot of DBS).
